# An example condition_variable::notify_one

Tags: c++, condition-variable

from

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
 
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
int i = 0;
bool done = false;
 
void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cout << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
    std::cout << "...finished waiting; i == " << i << '\n';
    done = true;
}
 
void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
    std::cout << "Notifying falsely...\n";
    cv.notify_one(); // waiting thread is notified with i == 0.
                     // cv.wait wakes up, checks i, and goes back to waiting
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(300ms); // Add to make sure 'waits' thread wakes up**
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    i = 1;
    while (!done) 
    {
        std::cout << "Notifying true change...\n";
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one(); // waiting thread is notified with i == 1, cv.wait returns**
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(300ms);
        lk.lock();
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits), t2(signals);
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join();
}
```

This is an example I got from cppreference. I have tried to execute the codes and observe the second notify seems not effected. Even I commented it out, the "signals" thread is still done.

Should it be put in the forever loop ??
Also if I add a wait before taking the cv_m mutex, seems it's working as expected

Comment: When I comment out the notification inside the loop, the waiting never ends: https://godbolt.org/z/hq4rvW9Ys. What is the question? I don't understand what you are asking about. The problem is that with the original code, the waiting thread is guaranteed to be notified. In your code, it is not guaranteed. Therefore, it may on may not be notified. Which is basically a _race condition_.

Comment: @DanielLangr The expectation is that the loop should not end with my change. Yep, That's because I added "**std::this_thread::sleep_for(300ms);" before "std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);"/. Refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one. It did not do the same that the loop still ends even commented the notification out in the loop. My question is the example shown in cppreference incorrect ?? I'm trying to correct but some guys there did not understand the issue

Comment: _"The expectation is that the loop should not end with my change."_ — Why do you think so? I don't think it is true. By adding some sleeping you won't get any guarantee that the loop will never end. It still may end. You cannot synchronize threads by putting them into sleep for some time, that's insane.

Comment: My point is that it may very well happen that `cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});` will never actually start waiting, because it will read 1 the first time this statement is executed.

Comment: I did run many times. With my change, the loop never ends. Very appreciate if you show me once the loop ends. Back to the example in cppreference, the loops still ends without the second notification [commented it out]. You can give a try and see.

Comment: _"With my change, the loop never ends."_ — I don't understand. What is your change? I thought your change was commenting out the second notification. But you say that _"the loop still ends"_ with it. So, does it end or does not?

Comment: My explanation for it is that if there is no sleeping time, the lock is still kept by "signal" thread [unique_ptr]. I suspect there is a race the first waking up never happens and the "signal" thread set i=1. Then when it unlocks lk, the waking up just happens and exits due to i = 1. Hence, the second notification is not affected in this cases. Putting the sleeping time ensure the "waits" thread wakes up and waits for the next notification

Comment: My change started with "**" as prefix. I have changed two lines

Comment: _"Putting the sleeping time ensure the "waits" thread wakes up and waits for the next notification."_ — That's wrong. Putting the sleeping time does not ensure this. Sleeping a thread for some time does not synchronize threads in any way. It may have the desired effect (this happened in my live demo I linked previously), but there is no guarantee. Try to add `std::err << i;` into the lambda body. BTW, what is your system configuration and a C++ compiler?

Comment: As your understanding, my change might not be exact but it can make the loop endless without the second notification. [Tried many times and see the same result].

Comment: I used gcc on OpenSUSE system

Comment: Sure, it may (see my live demo). This is what I already said before. Or, it may not. Trying many times does not change anything about it. You simply cannot synchronize threads by putting them to sleep for some time. This is a way to hell. Don't do it.

Comment: Let me clarify "Putting the sleeping time ensure the "waits" thread wakes up and waits for the next notification". It avoid the "signals" thread takes the lock immediately that prevents the "waits" thread from waking up. Just my guess but I might be not right. Only wanna get the exactly why the second notification is sometimes not affected as seen

Comment: _"Putting the sleeping time ensure the "waits" thread wakes up and waits for the next notification"_ — No, it does not. _It avoid the "signals" thread takes the lock immediately that prevents the "waits" thread waking up._ — Again, no, it does not. You cannot control a system scheduler. `sleep_for` does not guarantee that another thread will be executed while the current thread is blocked.

Comment: Just notice there is also a sleep after the second notification before locking the mutex but it had not been done for the first one

Comment: It doesn't matter. I will write it again, because it is likely the most important information: **`sleep_for` does not guarantee that another thread will be executed while the current thread is blocked**. It may very well happen that `signals()` writes 1 to `i` before `waits()` calls `cv.wait()`, regardless on sleeping.

Comment: You might not be understanding correctly, sleep_for does not not guarantee that another thread will be executed, what guarantees the blocking thread is executed is cv,notify_one(), sleep_for just blocks the current thread to not take the mutex immediately. Also the same mutex is used by condition variable internally

Comment: What in your modified code prevents the following scenario? First, `signals()` run the code from the beginning to `lk.unlock();` in the first loop iteration. Then, `waits()` starts running, locks the mutex, and reads `i` being already set to 1. Therefore, it does not start waiting at all. It writes `true` to `done`, and exits while releasing the mutex. Finally, `signals()` reacquires the mutex, reads `done` begin `true`, and exists (while releasing the mutex). Both threads are finished.

Comment: Now you understood what I fixed. Putting a sleep prevents the signal() from taking the mutex and let the waits() resume properly at the first notification.

Comment: Sorry but still don't. Your modifications in my opinion do not fix anything, since there is nothing wrong with the original code. But your code is wrong, since without notifications in the loop, the `wait()` can wait forever.

Comment: My code I posted is not correct but to demonstrate a scenario which is missing in the example code.  The correct fix is to just a sleep for the first notification. I will do fix it now

Comment: The scenario I described can happen with the original (cppreference) code as well.

Comment: Maybe, you should completely edit your question and 1) provide a modified code in the compilable form (avoid those `**` that prevent compilation), 2) very clearly formulate what you are asking about. I would also suggest to delete all the comments and to start again with the discussion.

Comment: That's true. I tried to fix it in cppreference but nobody got it and reverted the changes. so I opened the case here to get someone who can understand the issue. Now you are the first one. Not an easy thing to play with synchronization

Comment: Sorry but I am not. I still don't know what do you mean by "issue"? What is wrong with the original cppreference code in your opinion? I don't see anything wrong. If you want to make sure the waiting thread will actually wait for the notification, you cannot to this just by adding sleeping intervals. You would need to add some thread synchronization. But why? That example would get much more complicated.

Comment: If you want some example code where waiting for the notification is guaranteed, just look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable. The example taken from `notify_one` page does not guarantee that waiting will take place and there is nothing wrong about it.

Comment: The original code is not wrong but it did not handle well enough. If the word "issue" is confusing, I can change as "the second notification may not be affected sometimes". Is it okay ?? I wanna revise the notify_one example to everyone can understand the corner case

Comment: True, it may not. But why do you want to change it? Maybe, it's on purpose. Because it's quite important to see what can happen in practice. Notification that have no effects can be important to understand.

Comment: If you comment out the second notification, there are no guarantees. The wait might enfd. The wait might not end. The wait might end for you on Fridays and not end for me on Mondays, or vice versa. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I guess OP finds the example code on cppreference confusing and tries to change it into a form where waiting for a notification would be guaranteed.

Comment: If this is the purpose, I have no idea. But sure someone getting the original code can be misled to the behavior

Comment: I'm not sure what purpose you mean. The code at cppreference works. That's its purpose. If you make random changes to it, it may stop working. Why would anyone be misled by it?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. it works but not well, there is nothing in order to either guarantees the second notification wakes the waits up or becomes an ignored event. should change it  the second one is always caught

Comment: "it works but not well" In what sense exactly? Does the program crash, enters an infinite loop, or has any other undesired behaviour?

Comment: You need to go through the above comments. It was discussed clearly

Comment: Your comments are as far from clear as it gets. I cannot understand them at all. Please explain which **observable** behaviour of the original program is unsatisfying. Do you see output you do not expect to see? If you do not see any such output now, do you suspect that it is theoretically possible that you will see some one day? Note it doesn't matter how or why output is produced, as long as it is done legally.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The original code does NOT ensure the notifications to be caught properly. I have tried to point it out by commenting the second notification out and observe the program it still finished. Two threads are complete. I think there would be better ways to determine it but at least we can see even though not except modifying the std inside to have more debug. Definitely the output is still okay in both cases [with and without the change]

Comment: The unmodified program produces output it promises to produce. **This is all that matters**. The fact that you need to modify it means exactly that it works.You either don't understand how it works, or do not like the way how it works, but its purpose is to work, i.e. produce output, not please you with the method of doing so.

Comment: @nhatnq What do you mean by a notification being "caught properly"? Notifications do not need to be caught at all, which may happen here. There is nothing improper about it.

Comment: @DanielLangr I guess programmers don't want to write kinds of program that events could be ignored. If it's on purpose, I will not talk about it. Yep, it needs to be controlled, the final results are not concern, all roads lead to Rome so please don't mind . Initially looking at the original codes, I thought the idea of the owner is to have two notifications to be caught by the waiters

Comment: "The program doesn't work because a modified program doesn't work". Don't you see some kind of flaw in this reasoning? "I guess programmers don't want to write kinds of program that events could be ignored." The notification in the original program is meant to *ensure a condition*. If the condition holds anyway without it to be caught, then there is no reason for it to be caught. It is absolutely normal for notifications to go to waste, if they notify about something the intended recipient already knows.

Comment: I do say again it's still normal. Anyway on my view, I would need two notifications to be activated. Also not many people can perceive the scenario where the second one is not caught. So I only want to make clear that point. I don't argue true/false here